# To restrict Special Characters and allow alphabets

Tags: javascript

In the below code i want to allow alphaets and to restrict special characters.But it is allowing special characters.pls help me to solve this issue.

JS:

```
function AcceptAlphabetsOnly(e, t) {
    try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        }
        else { return true; }
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
};
```

Asp.net

```
<input name="data[Customer][name]" type="text" 
                             id="txtVendor" runat="server" onkeypress="return AcceptAlphabetsOnly(event,this);" />
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate, but not confident enough to swing Mjölnir. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514266/regular-expressions-jquery-check/24514433#24514433

Comment: Define "special". Is ö special? How about ß? How about ǃ (as in ǃXóõ)?

Comment: @Quentin i can't get you

Comment: @user3806185 — There are lots of different alphabets in the world and different people think different characters are "special". What do you mean by those terms?

Comment: @Quentin {@#$%^&*()+-} These spl chrs  i don't want to allow

Comment: @user3806185 — So you want to exclude *only* those characters, but the other thousands in unicode are fine?

Comment: @Quentin  yes i want to restrict those spl chars only

Comment: May I suggest a Regex for what you're trying to do?

Comment: @hex494D49 yes sure i have placed this js function in js folder and accessing in which fields are required

Comment: Then it's easy... this `([^0-9]+)` will exclude all numeric values, so add to it all special characters you won't, like these mentioned above `([^0-9{@#$%^&*()+-}]+)` and you're done And you will match all this `你好-κόσμος-wçčćšđž-ëö-ßóõ-abcd` as well

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function

```
function checkSpcialChar(event){
    if (!((event.keyCode >= 65) && (event.keyCode <= 90) || (event.keyCode >= 97) && (event.keyCode <= 122) || (event.keyCode >= 48) && (event.keyCode <= 57))) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        return;
    }
    event.returnValue = true;
}
```